# C#: WPD - Downloading a Picture with meta tags

Tags: jpeg, meta-tags, exif, smartphone, wpd

I am running the Portable Device API to automatically get Photos from a connected Smart Phone. I have it all transferring correctly. The code that i use is that Standard DownloadFile() routine:

```
    public PortableDownloadInfo DownloadFile(PortableDeviceFile file, string saveToPath)
    {
        IPortableDeviceContent content;
        _device.Content(out content);
        IPortableDeviceResources resources;
        content.Transfer(out resources);
        PortableDeviceApiLib.IStream wpdStream;
        uint optimalTransferSize = 0;
        var property = new _tagpropertykey
        {
            fmtid = new Guid(0xE81E79BE, 0x34F0, 0x41BF, 0xB5, 0x3F, 0xF1, 0xA0, 0x6A, 0xE8, 0x78, 0x42),
            pid = 0
        };
        resources.GetStream(file.Id, ref property, 0, ref optimalTransferSize, out wpdStream);

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream sourceStream =
            // ReSharper disable once SuspiciousTypeConversion.Global
            (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream)wpdStream;

        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.Name);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            return null;

        FileStream targetStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(saveToPath, filename),
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        try
        {
            unsafe
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    sourceStream.Read(buffer, 1024, new IntPtr(&bytesRead));
                    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, 1024);
                } while (bytesRead > 0);

                targetStream.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sourceStream);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wpdStream);
        }
        return pdi;
    }
}
```

There are two problems with this standard code:
1) - when the images are saves to the windows machine, there is no EXIF information. this information is what i need. how do i preserve it?
2) the saved files are very bloated. for example, the source jpeg is 1,045,807 bytes, whilst the downloaded file is 3,942,840 bytes!. it is similar to all of the other files. I would of thought that the some inside the unsafe{} section would output it byte for byte? Is there a better way to transfer the data? (a safe way?)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this. it works fine.. it is something else that is causing these issues

Comment: Can't you close your question?